# Why some system functions in T-SQL without parameters have parenthesis while others don't?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, function

I never remember if a system T-SQL function, with no parameters, requires parenthesis, so I wonder if there is a reason.

For example: **CURRENT_TIMESTAMP** is a function that doesn't require parenthesis, while **SCOPE_IDENTITY()** requires them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the differences are due to whether the function is a part of the ansi sql standard (which current_timestamp is) or whether it is a sql server function.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather think CURRENT_TIMESTAMP AS A SERVER VARIABLE..

Comment: The help explicitly states that it's a function ... Quote: "This function is the ANSI SQL equivalent to GETDATE"